# Remove TFoot when TBody tr's are empty

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with header,body and footer. when my table body is empty then i need to hide my table footer also.

My Code:

```
$("#tid tfoot tr").html("");
```

Comment: So if there is no data for your table, you don't want to show the footer, but the header should be there, right?

Comment: When you say empty, does that mean no rows?

Comment: @Dirk Horsten yes header should be there and don,t want to show the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TABLE id="myTable">
<THEAD>
     <TR> <TD>..HEADER.. </TD> </TR>
</THEAD>
<TBODY>
     <TR> <TD>...first row... </TD> </TR>
     <TR> <TD>...second row... </TD> </TR>
     <TR> <TD>...third row... </TD> </TR>
</TBODY>
<TFOOT>
     <TR> <TD>..FOOTER.. </TD> </TR>
</TFOOT>
</TABLE>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if(!$.trim($("#myTable tbody").html())) { // check if empty
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteTFoot(); // delete footer
  } 
});
</script>
```